# Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length

Tags: c#, asp.net, substring

I'm getting this error:

```
Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length
```

Using this code:

```
string a1 = ddlweek.Text.Substring(0, 8);                
string a3 = ddlweek.Text.Substring(10, 14);
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Index and length must refer to a location within the string error in substring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082803/index-and-length-must-refer-to-a-location-within-the-string-error-in-substring)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP never accepted the answer and there is no other defined process to handle such questions.

Answer (score 15):

If the length of your string (ddlweek) is 23 characters or less, you will get this error:

```
    string ddlweek = "12345678901234567890123";//This is NOK
    string a1 = ddlweek.Substring(0, 8);                
    string a3 = ddlweek.Substring(10, 14);
    Console.WriteLine("a1="+a1);
    Console.WriteLine("a3="+a3);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

The string should be at least 24 characters long..
You might consider adding an `if` to make sure everything is OK..

```
    string ddlweek = "123456789012345678901234";//This is OK
    string a1 = ddlweek.Substring(0, 8);                
    string a3 = ddlweek.Substring(10, 14);
    Console.WriteLine("a1="+a1);
    Console.WriteLine("a3="+a3);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 7):

It means that your `ddlweek.Text` string contains less number of characters than what you asked for in `Substring(index, length)`.

Example:

```
if (ddlweek.Text.Length >= 8)
    string a1 = ddlweek.Text.Substring(0, 8);
```

Answer (score 3):

It just means you're asking for a substring of *ddlweek* that doesn't exist (ie, it's more than 24 characters in length).

Answer (score 3):

this error occurs when you exceed your end limit of total character.
for example

```
        string name = "iLovePakistan"; // Here i want to print only Pakistan

        string name2 = name.Substring(5, 150); // this code will throw same error. just replace 150 with name.Length - 5

        string name3 = name.Substring(5, name.Length - 5); // i skip firt 5 charchers then name.Length-5 means print rest 8 characters.

        string name4 = name.Substring(5, 8); // This will do exactly as name3
        Console.WriteLine(name4);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Substring(startIndex,length);
```

**startIndex** : Gets the first value you want to get. 0 Begins.

**length** : The size of the value you get (How many digits you will get).

```
string Code = "KN32KLSW";
string str = Code.Substring(0,2);
Console.WriteLine("Value : ",str);
```

On the Console screen : **KN**

```
string str = Code.Substring(3,4);
Console.WriteLine("Value : ",str);
```

On the Console screen : **2KLS**