# Index and length must refer to a location within the string error in substring

Tags: c#, .net, string, substring, string-length

I have a string like this: `2899 8761  014 00:00:00 06/03/13 09:35 G918884770707`. I have to take the substring `G918884770707` from this given string. I know the start of the substring so I'm taking the end of the substring as the length of the whole string like this:

```
 No = line.Substring(Start,End);
```

Here the value of Start is `39` and the length of the main string is `52` so this is the value for End.

This causes the error:

> Index and length must refer to a location within the string error in substring

How do I resolve this?

Comment: `string Substring(int startIndex, int length)` not `string Substring(int startIndex, int endIndex)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've misunderstood the parameters to [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) - they aren't start and end (as they are in Java), they're start and *length*.

So you want:

```
No = line.Substring(Start, End - Start);
```

From the docs:

> **Parameters** 
>   *startIndex*
>   Type: `System.Int32`
>   The zero-based starting character position of a substring in this instance.
>
> *length*
>   Type: `System.Int32`
>   The number of characters in the substring.
>
> **Return Value**
>   Type: `System.String`
>   A string that is equivalent to the substring of length length that begins at startIndex in this instance, or Empty if startIndex is equal to the length of this instance and length is zero.

Always, always read the documentation - particularly if you're getting an exception that you don't understand.